# DC coupled common emitter amplifier

Tags: transistors, potentiometer, emitter-follower

I am designing a DC supply for a motor driver. The voltage of the supply determines the motor speed (voltage goes up, speed goes up). My plan is to vary the supply voltage to keep the motor rotation synchronized with an external oscillator.

Following the recommendation of the motor driver designer, I am placing the supply input of the motor driver at the output of an emitter follower amplifier (with a Darlington transistor, for sufficient current gain):

[image: dc coupled emitter folower]

So R4 would in principle be the motor driver supply input. My anticipated operating procedure would be:

1. Ground Vin
2. Tune the potentiometer (R5) to approximately match the motor speed with that of the reference oscillator.
3. "Close the feedback loop". Integrate Vin into a servo loop to keep fixed the phase between the motor rotation and reference oscillator oscillations.

Some simple calculations, ignoring the input impedance of R4 through the high current gain NPN base-emitter junction, we get that for \$\frac{R5}{R1} \equiv \epsilon \ll 1\$ a "gain" \$\frac{\Delta Vout}{\Delta Vin} \approx \epsilon\$, which is in fact desirable if we are only anticipating minor corrections from the feedback loop to the voltage set by the potentiometer R5. Similarly the maximum achievable setpoint with Vin grounded is only reduced by a factor of \$1 + \epsilon\$.

My question is: should I be wary of this design? This seems like a nice way to avoid an extra op-amp to sum the large DC bias voltage to the small correction voltage. However a google search for "DC-coupled emitted follower" does not return much so I am worried there is a good reason to avoid this design.

One potential issue is a drift of the bias point due to a temperature change in the potentiometer, though of course the change should be small \$\frac{\Delta Vout}{\Delta Vin} \approx \epsilon \frac{\Delta R5}{R5}\$ if the temperature drifts only affect the total resistance R5 and not the ratio of the resistances from the center tap to the end taps of the pot. Are there potentiometers (ideally multi-turn) that are well-suited to this task?

Comment: How much stall current does the motor take? How long to come out of stall to running speed both with and without mechanical load?

Comment: @Andyaka the stall current is 0.6 amps. I am not sure about the start up time.